# Redirect to a external link if state not found

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm building an angular application where I need to redirect a user to an external link if the state is not found ('otherwise').

I'm using UI-Router.

Could not find any examples.
Any help will be appreciated!

**UPDATE** :

I was able to achieve redirecting to external link by passing a function to otherwise :

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function() {
    window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
  });
```

Thanks for the help and sorry for lack of clarity!

Comment: `window.open('link to external resource');`

Comment: How can I implement it inside of a 'state' .. ?

Comment: Maybe you can redirect to a state with a controller hadling the redirection.

Comment: Did not think of that, let me try and get back to you. thanks! :)

Comment: @IliaSokolovski What  you're doing isn't typical. Sounds like you have an X/Y problem. You're asking how to accomplish your solution to your problem rather than asking how to solve your problem. That's a whole other question at this point. It's almost always best to define a route and do something with it rather than intentionally assigning a non-existent route. As Deblaton pointed out, you could use that state's controller. You can also use `$rootScope.$on('stateChangeStart', function(e, toState) {
  if (toState === 'your-state-name') {
    $window.location = //etc
  }
})`

Comment: It is much clearer if you post the solution as an answer rather than an update to the question.  Self Answers are perfectly acceptable and encouraged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want the `stateNotFound` event:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router'])
.config(function($stateProvider) {

})
.run(function($rootScope, $window) {
  $rootScope.$on('$stateNotFound', function(){
    // go somewhere else
    $window.open('//google.com');
    // or use $window.location = url here;
  });
});
```

[**Live demo (click here).**](http://jsbin.com/juvizuzero/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: for some reason it wont redirect, I just have that one state configured. :X

Comment: @IliaSokolovski I'm not sure what you're saying. I included a live demo demonstrating the solution - it works. If you're having further problems, you need to share your code and preferably also create a live demo.

Comment: I've created a live demo which is close to what I have, slightly modified yours - http://jsbin.com/quqebilezi/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @IliaSokolovski The code is fine. It's a cross-domain issue because you used `_self`. That's why I didn't use `location = url`. You need to open it in a new window. You should observe the developer console. `Refused to display 'https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'`

Comment: @IliaSokolovski Here's a demo where the other server allows cross-domain. Works just fine: http://jsbin.com/cucamuhiji/1/edit?html,js,output